# i want to have a index vector

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-coder

I want to crop an image. I have initial points(x,y) and width and height of area which I want. but initial points and width and height are not constant. Because I think I can crop with selector. That's why I regulated index vector (port) but need a index vector. I think MATLAB function able to help me. I wrote function but it error me 
-Data 'y' (#48) is inferred as a variable size matrix, while its specified
type is something else.-
my function is 
function:

```
y = fcn(u,v)
%#codegen

y = [u:1:v];
```

What can I do for getting a index vector?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/variable-size-signal-basics.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have the initial position, and width and height, why can't you do something like the following, or am I not understanding correctly?

```
pep = imread('peppers.png');
imshow(pep)
initialX = 100;
initialY = 100;
width = 50;
height = 150;
pep2 = pep(initialX:initialX+height,initialY:initialY+width,:);
figure
imshow(pep2)
```

Of course in this simple case the values are constant, but this does not have to always be true.